# How to deal with grep failure returning integer(0) in R?

Tags: r, return-value

In the grep expression,when the value of grep is `integer(0)`,print "ok",how can i do?

```
> data="haha"
> grep("w",data)
integer(0)
> if (grep("w",data)==0) print ("ok")
Error in if (grep("w", data) == 0) print("ok") : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use either `length` or `identical`

```
R> if (length(grep("w", data)) == 0) print ("ok")
[1] "ok"

R> if (identical(grep("w", data), integer(0))) print ("ok")
[1] "ok"
```

You could also use `grepl` instead of `grep`

```
R> if (!any(grepl("w", data))) print('ok')
[1] "ok"
```

Comment: If you know that data is a single value, you can use `if (grepl("w", data))`. Which happens in OPs case and in my code now too...

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `grep`, youcould use  `grepl` which returns a logical:

```
> if (grepl("w",data)== FALSE) print ("ok") else print("donkeykong")
[1] "ok"


> if (grepl("h",data)== FALSE) print ("ok") else print("donkeykong")
[1] "donkeykong"
```

Comment: if `data` is length greater than 1, you'll get a warning

Comment: @Gsee - valid point, at which point I'd probably recommend using `ifelse()` instead if you want a vectorized solution...or `any()` as you suggested, cleverly. I'm not in the habit of mind reading on Fridays though - it's the OP's responsibility to come up with something representative of their problem :)